# How to have a global action in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, action

I have a Contact Form on all pages of my website, and instead of having it someone to just one area of the site, I would like it processed on any page it is on. Is it possible to add a global action? I am assuming I need to make a base controller and constructor and listen to if someone submits the form? Can someone let me know and/or lead me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything like that.

You should put that contact form in a shared partial view, include it in the layout / master page, and make it post to a separate controller.

Comment: I suppose I could use AJAX on it which would allow it to post to a separate controller.

Comment: You don't need AJAX; you can do a normal POST to a separate controller too.

Comment: Yes but the user needs to remain on the page where they called the contact form from.

Comment: Then you can include the current URL (`Request.Url.PathAndQuery`) in the form and return a redirect to that URL.  However, you'll probably want to use AJAX anyway.